# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

```
export class PostEditComponent implements OnInit {
form! : FormGroup;
  index: number =0;
  route: any;
  editMode = false;
  
  constructor(private postService: PostService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    let title = '';
    let describtion = '';
    let imagePath ='';
   
    this.route.params.subscribe((params:Params) => {
      if(params['index']){
        console.log(params['index']);

        this.index = params["index"];

        console.log(
        this.postService.getPost(this.index));

        // const post= this.postService.getPosts(this.index);
        // title=post.title;
        // describtion=post.description;
        // imagePath =post.imagePath;
        // this.editMode=true;

      }
    });

HTMl code: <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>Post Add...</h3>
        <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label> Title</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="title" name="title"><br>
                <label> Description</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="description" name="description"></textarea><br>
                <label> Image Path</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="imagePath" name="imagePath"><br>
                <img class="img-responsive" src="{{form.value.imagePath}}">

                <!-- <span *ngIf="title.invalid && title.touched" style="color:red">Title is Required</span> -->
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" [disabled]="form.invalid">Save</button> |
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="reset" (click)="reset()">Clear</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have to try to do when we are click on edit button on existing  blog then we open with  data show on edit post page with existing data will  show and we have to edit and save the new  content  same page[enter image description here][1]
[enter image description here][2]

Comment: please rephrase your question, people can have trouble to understand it. You can use google translator and use your mother tongue to be as precise as possible and then just translate it with any online service

Comment: try  `this.router` instead of `this.route` as you declared in your constructor

Answer (score 1):

You have used Routes to get data from URL, you need to use **ActivatedRoute** service to get params from URL.

```
    import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
    
    constructor(private postService: PostService, 
                private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }
    
    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
          if(params != null && params.index != null){
             console.log(params['index']);
             this.index = params["index"];
        }
      });
    }
```

Activated route in angular docs :
https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute